# how to cast object to double type array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, hashmap

OK so what if i have a method like:

```
Object[] myTest(int[] a, double[] b){
   return new Object[]{a,b};
}
```

Now How can i cast the result Object to int[] and double[]?

Like if i use:

```
int[] array1 = (int[]) myTest(a,b)[0];
double[] array2 = (double[]) myTest(a,b)[1];
```

But this does not work. Or is there any efficient method to do this job?

Comment: This is very poor design.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Martel, sorry i was wrong.
@SLaks, why you think this is poor design??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're having difficulty: on Java 6 this works as expected.

Try compiling this class and running it:

```
public class t1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
    int[] a = new int[1];
    double[] b = new double[1];

    int[] array1 = (int[]) myTest(a,b)[0];
    double[] array2 = (double[]) myTest(a,b)[1];
    System.err.println(array1);
    System.err.println(array2);
    }

    static Object[] myTest(int[] a, double[] b){
    return new Object[]{a,b};
    }
}
```

it will print out

```
[I@3e25a5
[D@19821f
```

That's the autoboxing taking place, but will still work.

Comment: Why do you use `System.err.println()`?

Comment: Haha. Simpler keystrokes (I can use one finger to type **err** since *e* and *r* are side by side; **out** involves 2 fingers).

Comment: thanks, it is actually working. I did not know this strange problem with Eclipse, but now its' working:)))

Answer (score 2):

Have a WrapperObject that contains int[] and double[] . Use getters to access them.

```
public class WrapperObject {

     private int[] a;
     private double[] b;

     public void setA(int[] a1) {
         a = a1;
     }

     public int[] getA() {
         return a;
     }
    .....
}
```

Let your myTest method return that object.

```
public WrapperObject myTest(int[] a , double[] b) {
      return new WrapperObject(a, b);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the details. I just realized my method also works. I don't know why it didn't initially.

Answer (score 2):

Although your code is working fine with me, but you could do it in another way:

```
public static Object myTest(int[] a, double[] b, int index)
{
    Object[] obj = {a,b};
    return obj[index];
}
```

Then use it like:

```
int[] array1 = (int[]) myTest(a,b,0);
double[] array2 = (double[]) myTest(a,b,1);
```

Comment: yes thanks, I just realized it works. I don't know initially i tried but always had this type error of casting.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wrapper:

```
Integer[] array = (Integer[]) myTest()
```